# Filtering points in d3 using using equality statement to return results

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, gis, geojson

I would like to filter the points displayed on a map based on attribute, with checkboxes.

I successfully render points on the map.

```
 var chicagoCrimes = svg.append( "g" );
    
        chicagoCrimes.selectAll( "path" )
            .data( Crimes.features )
            .enter()
            .append( "path" )
            .attr( "pointRadius", "10px" )
            .attr("class","incident")
```

Here, I create checkboxes with which to filter points based on crime type.

```
    <div class="filter_options">
    <input class="filter_button" id="HOMICIDE" type="checkbox">a</input><br>
    <input class="filter_button" id="ROBBERY" type="checkbox">b</input><br>
    <input class="filter_button" id="ASSAULT" type="checkbox">c</input><br>
```

I assign a value to each checkbox:

```
document.getElementById("HOMICIDE").value = "HOMICIDE"
document.getElementById("ASSAULT").value = "ASSAULT"
```

Then, I want to match the value of checkbox to value of crime type (`Primary_Type`) in my data:

```
d3.selectAll(".filter_button").on("change", function() {
  var type = this.value, 
  display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
  console.log(type)
  svg.selectAll(".incident")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Primary_Type === type; })
    .attr("display", display)
});
```

However, no filtering occurs, though it doesn't throw an error.  I think the equality statement above is not working correctly; i.e not matching the `Primary_Type` of data properties w/ value type of checkboxes.  Underlying data is structured as such:

```
var Crimes = {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
 "features": [{
   "type": "Feature", "properties": {
     "ID": 23757, "Case Number": "JB100159", "Date": "1\/1\/18 2:46", "Block": "039XX W CORNELIA AVE", "IUCR": "110", "Primary_Type": "HOMICIDE", "Description": "FIRST DEGREE MURDER", "Location Description": "AUTO", "Arrest": "FALSE", "Domestic": "FALSE", "Beat": 1732, "District": 17, "Ward": 30, "Community Area": 21, "FBI Code": "01A", "X Coordinate": 1149289, "Y Coordinate": 1922972, "Year": 2018, "Updated On": "1\/8\/18 15:55", "Latitude": 41.94456125, "Longitude": -87.72668181, "Location": "(41.944561251, -87.726681812)"
   },
   "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -87.72668181, 41.94456125 ] }
},
{
```

Comment: In general, this type of issue can be easily solved with a few `console.log` statements or by running through the code with a debugger and checking the values.

Comment: i have - the value is reading correctly from check-box..

Comment: Can you create a minimal complete example and/or add a link to a jsfiddle / block showing the problem? It looks like it should work, so maybe the issue is elsewhere or something subtle.